# Automatic Encoding and Decoding in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I obtain Automatic Encoding and Decoding URL parameter in MVC4?

I want to make encoding and decoding for parameter only and for all scenario(from view, from controller redirect action). If you can give answer with code example then that will be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use .net Inbuilt feature to do this.

from `System.Web.HttpUtility.*`

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.Form["from"])
System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Form["from"])
```

I use it in my apps and it's work fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Razor View:

```
@Html.Encode(....)
@Html.Raw(....)
```